# Update the help page for editing your account credentials

Tags: feature-request, help-center

The screenshots and explanation on the "[Edit Credentials](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials)" have not been updated to match the new user pages.

[image: Current view of edit credentials]

This seems to be the case [network-wide](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials).

Could these images be updated to reflect the current user experience?

Comment: Help pages are seeded network-wide from the same shared copy, so it makes sense you'd see this network-wide.